# internal website - can't access from outside

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, web-server

At first it worked fine. I was running Apache on CentOS 5.5. I remember I didn't change any fancy settings to my Apache, just some virtual hosts.

Then yesterday I reinstall that server with CentOS 6.2. Installed apache and everything else. Now I can't access the website through our dyndns-ip anymore. Can anyone help? Here are some information.

- the LAN set up is very simple. A modem, a few switches, all machines are workgrouped.
- The modem, 192.168.1.1 already has port 80 forwarding to the web server
- We can still browse the site using internal domain name and internal ip that points to the server.

It's when we try to access our site with dyndns-ip address that it doesn't work. We can still ping the site tho.

Here are parts of my httpd.conf that I think are relevant. xyz.dyndns-ip.com is not the real address by the way.

```
listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/www/html
    ServerName www.riffhub.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/www/html
    ServerName xyz.dyndns-ip.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried  nmap -p 80 xyz.dyndns-ip.com and port 80 is indeed available.

How should I start fixing this problem? Any help appreciate, thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like the virtual host isn't set up to listen on the dyndns host name?

Comment: listen 80 - is what I have. Are there other settings I should try?

Comment: What happens if you try to access directly your external IP?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `<VirtualHost>` container either has ServerName or a ServerAlias directive set to the dyndns host name, e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName internal-host.localnet
  ServerAlias dyndns-address.example.com
  [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi al4. I tried both ServerName and ServerAlias, both didn't work.